# Storm: set log level for topology

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, apache-storm

Apache Storm

How I can set log level for new topology and for exist once?

In java I wrote:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(MyClass.class);
...
LOG.debug("my debug log");
LOG.info("my info log");
```

and I see line with "my info log" but I dont see "my debug log" in worker.log file.

Comment: what logging library are you using? you should retag the question

Comment: I use SLF4J logger

Comment: I think no. It will be work for self application but I writing module for Apache Storm. I think I need set it in height level near Storm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decision:

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/36203/debugging-an-apache-storm-topology-1.html

The best way for set log level of all topology:

```
./bin/storm set_log_level my_topology -l ROOT=DEBUG:30
```